# Long Distance High Speed Wireless Data Transfer

Tags: circuit-design, wireless, design, radio, signal-theory

What kind of device can I use to transmit data at a rate of 1MB/min up to a distance of 100 miles? If that's not possible, what's the farthest distance to which I can transmit the data.

Comment: What kind of device? A radio. If you want a more specific answer, you need to add a lot more detail to your question. What constraints does your application put on the solution? For that kind of bandwidth over that kind of distance, you'll need a licensed device. By far, the simplest solution these days is to use the cellphone network.

Comment: You could use a socket connection through a GSM modem.

Comment: You can use [IPoAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers). If you want a better answer than that, you need to add details.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of device can I use to transmit data at a rate of 1Mb/ min
>   upto a distance of 100 miles?

Anything you ask is physically possible but maybe not legal in your area.

To receive data at 17 kbps (1 Mb per minute) there is an empirical formula that tells you what power needs to come from your receive antenna: -

Power = -154 dBm + 10\$log_{10}\$(data rate) = -112 dBm

Then there is the link loss equation that tells you roughly how much attenuation you will get between transmit antenna and receive antenna: -

Loss (dB) = 32.45 + 20\$log_{10}\$(f) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d)

The distance d, is in kilometres and f is the transmit carrier frequency in MHz

100 miles is 161 km and if you transmitted at (say) 100 MHz, the link loss would be 32.45 dB + 40 dB + 44.14 dB = 116.59 dB.

On the face of it you would need to transmit about +4.59 dBW but this can be reduced if you have antenna gain so, using simple dipoles (about 2 dB gain at each end) you would be transmitting about a watt at 100 MHz. However, this gives a very unreliable link and you would need to factor in something like an extra 20 or 30 dB for fading effects.

You would also need to ensure that your antennas were line-of-sight to each other and this is not so easy over a distance of 161 km.

Plus, it's probably illegal to transmit such high power at 100 MHz in most areas of the world so you would need to research a frequency where it is allowable at the powers needed.

Comment: The practical answer is that the transmitter is going to be microwave and highly directional. But that brings its own problems with weather etc

Comment: If you drop to 1MHz (middle of AM band), requiring HUGE antennas to sustain the link-margins, these antennas needing to be installed high up, your power drops to 100 microWatts. With all the challenges of multipathing and fading Andy warned of. Consider using 64QAM, so the energy looks like "noise" and will correlate poorly with AM stations, so causes low interference; at 6 bits per symbol/baud, you only need 3KHz bandwidth and can work anywhere.